# 15 Pin Serial Cable?

Tags: cable, serial-port

Stumbled across what appears to be a 15pin serial cable when cleaning out the equipment room today.  I'm familiar with 25 pin and  Any idea what these are commonly used for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hard to tell without a pic, but I'd guess its a 'DB Connector' or 'Game Port' connector.

> **DB-15 (DA-15 and DE-15)**
>   Two DB-15
>   connectors are widely used. The
>   larger, two-row female DA-15 is the
>   game port on a PC, and the smaller,
>   three-row, female high-density DE-15
>   is the VGA port.

The Game Port was used for joysticks, midi devices and other peripherals.

[image]

[source](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,2542,t=D-sub+connectors&i=55439,00.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of our earlier generation terminal concentrator units ran on an RS-422 loop that used DB-15 connectors and cabling.

Answer (score 0):

I am holding in my hand a Jam Studio KG-TAB1 drawing tablet, (c) 2000, that interfaces through a connector consisting of three rows of five holes, very much like a VGA connector but which surely cannot be VGA, given the application as an input device.  Other people discussing "the same" device mention its "USB" and "PS/2" connectors, which suggests serial communication over several stages of hardware evolution, further supporting the theory that this IS a serial device/port. I have also found online documentation of what claims to be the pinouts for serial communication on this style of connector.

Comment: The plug, in question, is 15pin and your answer does not apply.  I am resisting the urge to downvote it, as I am supposed to.